# SMS same text to multiple contacts

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I SMS same text to multiple Contacts in Wp7? I place all the Contacts mobile No in a List. 
Any issue if user accidentally press back Key button during the sending process in a loop?

```
SmsComposeTask sms = new SmsComposeTask();
sms.To = "0123456789";
sms.Body = "Some prefilled text...";

sms.Show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/220969/529252.aspx, it seems like all you have to do is delimit multiple phone numbers with a semicolon:

> sms.To = "First number; second number;
>   third number";

Answer (score -2):

The `SmsComposeTask`, which is the only way to programmatically send an SMS message, only allows you to specify a single recipient. However, when the SMS application is launched, the user can add more recipients if necessary.

If you use a loop to send an SMS messages to multiple recipients, the user could simply cancel the send of any one message by pressing the Back button without sending. Control will not be passed back to your application until they either press the back button.

Comment: ThankQ. case(1): use foreach loop thru the Mobile No List. How it works? The SMS Native App will Open and send and pass control back to the loop for the Next? case(2). Add other Mobile No when the Native SMS app launch, this is ok. But if I am in a very demanding environment where I dont have time to type of search. I guess this no solution. I hope it can hv this capability from winMo 6.x.